# get output from module called in a loop in bicep

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

How can I retrieve the output variable from a module called in a loop?
I like to add subnets in the next step to the vnet.

Main.bicep

```
module vnet01 'vNet.bicep' = [ for vnet in vnets :  { 
        name: vnet.name
        scope:  virtualNetworkRg
        params: { 
          vnetName: vnet.name
          vnetAddressPrefix: vnet.vnetAddressPrefix
          location: location
        }
      }]
```

vNet.bicep

```
param ...

resource vnet 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks@2021-08-01' = {
  name: vnetName
  location: location
  properties: {
    addressSpace: {
      addressPrefixes: [
        vnetAddressPrefix
      ]
    }
  }
}

//Output
output id string = vnet.id
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could always loop through `vnet01`  (as it is an array):

```bicep
module vnet01 'vNet.bicep' = [for vnet in vnets: {
  name: vnet.name
  ...
}]

output vnetIds array = [for i in range(0, length(vnets)): {
  id: vnet01[i].outputs.id
}]
```

Comment: this results in 'Directly referencing a resource or module collection is not currently supported here. Apply an array indexer to the expression.bicep'